# Wrong output from php function Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

My code is as follows:

```
class Database  
{  
    private $db_host;  
    private $db_user;  
    private $db_pass;  
    private $db_name;  
    private $con;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db_host = "localhost";  
        $this->db_user = "admin";  
        $this->db_pass = 'password';  
        $this->db_name = 'test';    
        $this->con = '';
    }

    public function connect() {
        $db_name = "test";    
        $this->con = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    }  

    public function select(){
        $q = "SELECT name, city FROM customers;";
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->con);
        $result = mysql_query($q);
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }  
} 


$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$tempArray = Array();
$rs = $db->select('customers', 'name, suburb');
foreach ($rs as $row)
{
    echo $rs['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

And my table's data is

```
name | city
--------------
Anne | Sydney
Jane | London
```

The actual output is:

```
Anne 
Anne
```

The desired output is:

```
Anne
Jane
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. It seems like I have missed something basic. I have read over 50 articles and nothing seems to explain what I am doing wrong.

Note: This is a scaled down version of my code. I intend to use this to make a more general object that pulls information from my database.

Thanks,

Brett

Comment: just to let you know, your "select" function makes no sense.  database class have to be used to run custom queries, not hardcoded ones.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I'm sure he just put that line in to minimize the possibility a mistake in the parameters, just for debugging, right? -- Clearly planning on changing it to work sensibly after he figured out what the problem was.

Comment: @Ben Oh. I am not that good in telepathy :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense, just common sense, eh? ;)

Comment: But in all seriousness, I can't bring myself to believe the OP would miss something of that magnitude. Seems like a case of debugging to me.

Comment: @Ben Well, I'd rather use my experience with this kind questions. Most of time the code being added not by some intelligent design but by quite random pasting from various sources. Also, the word 'debugging' is hardly known in the PHP world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for *each* row. It only returns one row of data, not the full set. For example, you could move it out into the loop:

```
class Database
{  
    /* ... */

    public function select(){
        $q = "SELECT name, city FROM customers;";
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->con);
        return mysql_query($q);
        /* Remove your line here, returning the query result, not the first row */
    }  
} 

$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$tempArray = Array();
$result = $db->select('customers', 'name, suburb');
/* Note that I'm now using mysql_fetch_assoc to get each row from the result */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

You can use a `while` loop there because after the last row has been retrieved, `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return FALSE and exit the loop.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that worked a charm! Re @Sudhir and other helps. I am sorry but I won't be trying your solutions because this is elegant and it works. Thanks to everyone. :-)

Comment: I don't entirely get the down-vote, but even your suggested change doesn't reflect the fact that the `select()` function is being called differently than it's defined, which is one reason the OP doesn't get the answer he expects.

Comment: @Brett it is not elegant by any means, because it's just a replica of your ugly code. But I do understand a desire to have not the good code but the code that at least works. Good luck :)

Comment: @TiesonT, actually according to his description, he was showing actual/expected results based on the inside query. A case of putting a debug line in to minimize the scope of the problem case.

Comment: I can see what he wants, but I also see an oddity in how his code is written. Either way, problem solved. Good work. :)

Comment: My code was odd because I wanted to keep it simple so people would want to solve it. The real code was about five times as long.

Answer (score 0):

In this section of your code:

```
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You are merely returning the first row. I suggest you to create an array.

```
public function select(){
    $q = "SELECT name, city FROM customers;";
    mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->con);
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $toReturn = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
        $toReturn[] = $row;
    return $toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. Why load the entire result set into memory at once? In many cases, that's insane.

Comment: (Having an option to load the entire result set like in @YourCommonSense's answer is okay, so you can use it in places you know it will be okay this instance; but don't make it the *only* option).

Answer (score 0):

Should'nt it be :

```
foreach ($rs as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

And:

```
$resArr = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $resArr[] = $res;
}
return $resArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

A sane version of your class. It lacks vital parts of course, to be used in the real life, but just out of your sketch:

```
class Database  
{  
    private $con;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", 'password');
        mysql_select_db("test",$this->con);
    }
    public function query($sql,$this->con){
        return mysql_query($sql);
    }  
    public function get_all($sql,$this->con){
        $ret = array();
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        while  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
          $ret[] = $row;
        }
        return $ret;
    }  
} 

$db = new Database();
$rs = $db->get_all("SELECT name, city FROM customers");
foreach ($rs as $row)
{
    echo $rs['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems kind of odd that no one has picked up on a bit of a gaff in the code here.

You define `select()` like so:

```
public function select(){
    $q = "SELECT name, city FROM customers;";
    mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->con);
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

But, then you call it like this:

```
$rs = $db->select('customers', 'name, suburb');
```

I assume your intention was to be able to specify the table and the fields to select from the database. If it was, your `select` function should look more like this:

```
public function select($table, $fields){
    $q = "SELECT $fields FROM $table;";
    mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->con);

    return mysql_query($q);
}
```

From there you would follow @BenLee's example in his answer, since you need to iterate over a resultset. Each field becomes a key in an associative array.

I wouldn't recommend actually doing string insertion like this in production code, but I think it's closer to what you intended.

HTH.

Comment: I'd +1 this answer if such a method was viable in the real life. but selecting whole table contents hardly can be used in the environment other than educational...

Comment: Heh. I also wouldn't ever use the mysql library, but everyone seems to refuse to stop, so what can you do?

Comment: that's another matter. there are no reasons to stop other than some laziness of the some PHP team.